# How do I set the gradle version in Android studio 1.3?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have updated to Android studio to version 1.3. In my project I need to use gradle version 2.2.1 and android gradle plugin version 1.0.0. How can I set android studio to use gradle version 2.2.1 automatically?

I have set the gradle wrapper-properities to 2.2.1 and in the project stucture it also shows it is using gradle version 2.2.1

## gradle-wrapper.properties

```
#Wed Apr 10 15:27:10 PDT 2013
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle2.2.1-all.zip
```

## Output:

> *Error:Gradle 2.4 requires Android Gradle plugin 1.2.0 (or newer)  but project is using version 1.0.0.
>   Please use Android Gradle plugin 1.2.0 or Fix plugin version and sync project*

I want to use Gradle 2.2.1 but it keeps jumping to 2.4

Comment: any **good** reasons for using outdated  Android Gradle plugin ?

Comment: Yes I am using ParseLoginUI for android on github, it only can use this version.  From the docs "If you are using gradle 1.1.0 or above, you may encounter "Warning:Project ParseLoginUI: provided dependencies can only be jars. com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:aar:4.0.1 is an Android Library". It is an open issue of android gradle build tool. Currently the workround is using gradle 1.0.0."

Comment: Thank you. Me too! I don't like Gradle.

Answer (score 17):

I was getting the same error in Android Studio and it turns out that Android Studio was pointing to it's own version of gradle instead of my project gradle wrapper.

For Windows Android Studio, Go into File > Settings > "Build, Execution, Deployment" > "Build Tools" > Gradle
and change it to "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)".

This fixed it for me without having to change the dependencies. Hopefully, this is all you need.

Answer (score 3):

In your project's build.gradle (NOT your app's module) make sure that its using android gradle build tools of 1.2.0 or above. So in your file, the dependency section should look something like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.+'
}
```

If you always want the lastest gradle build tools, change it to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
}
```

From OP:

This dosnt solve my problem.
I need to user plugin version 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0' in my project, so i have set it to this in my project build.gradle file. The problem I have is that this worked with using gradle 2.2.1 but since android Studio 1.3 is using gradle 2.4 it is not working. So I need to somehow get android studio to use gradle version 2.2.1 so i can use gradle plugin 1.0.0 .

Comment: Don't do this. The latest is `1.3.0`. This has nothing to do with `Gradle` anyways.

Comment: I need to user plugin version 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0' in my project, so i have set it to this in my project build.gradle file.  The problem I have is that this worked with using gradle 2.2.1 but since android Studio 1.3 is using gradle 2.4 it is not working. So I need to somehow get android studio to use gradle version 2.2.1 so i can use gradle plugin 1.0.0  .

Comment: oh wait, you definitely need 1.0.0 for some reason? You can't just update the build tools to the lastest version?

Comment: @JaredBurrows Correct me if I am wrong, but the problem is not Gradle. It is the build tools version he is using. Android Studio users Gradle v.2.4 so he has to update the build tools to work with the new Gradle version.

Comment: @FergalFitz Please refer to the answer from Mohammad Arman. Unless there is a very specific reason why you need the 1.0.0 version, you should just be updating your build tools. There will not be any complications.

Comment: @Sree No , I need to to use Gradle v.2.2.1 . My project dosnt work with any version above 1.0.0 .

Comment: Ah, then refer to Jordi's answer

Comment: You should use the latest Gradle and latest Android plugin to avoid problems like these.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use latest `Gradle` thats why **Android Studio** warns to upgrade it to the newest version.

Why you want to switch back to the older version?

**Note:** *If you are thinking the newer version will create any complication in your stable code, they be assured that it will not cause any harm to you code. And you can't attain any extra benefit from the older version. Newer version means more efficient and bug free thing.*

Comment: I have a module in my project that only works with 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0' . It does not work with newer versions.