# Fix Plugin Version and Sync Project

Tags: android

I have recently updated my Android Studio.
After updating it, When I am trying to import or open a project it gives me following error :

```
Gradle Sync Issue
Error:Error:Gradle 2.4 requires Android Gradle plugin 1.2.0 (or newer)  but project is using version 1.1.0.
Please use Android Gradle plugin 1.2.0 or newer.
Fix plugin version and sync project
```

Is there any solution for this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your build.gradle you should use a newer version of the gradle plugin.

Use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'`instead of `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'`. Or at least 1.2.0, as the error points out.

Comment: Its allri8, But, I have to do it manually for every time, when i am open my old project. Is there any way to set classpath automatically when opening my old project ?

Comment: Why don't you update/save the new config on your old project?

Comment: I meant that when i am opening every different project. Its work fine when i update/save the new config in my old(particular) project.

Answer (score 2):

change in your progect build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As Android Studio was just officially updated to 1.3 ***(Gradle as well).***

Please Change **gradle version to 1.3.+ in build.gradle** . It should now look like this:

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.+'

     // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I met this question,too. Modifying dependencies stuff is confuse me. From[@Mykaelos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31812907/how-do-i-set-the-gradle-version-in-android-studio-1-3), For Windows Android Studio, Go into File > Settings > "Build, Execution, Deployment" > "Build Tools" > Gradle and change it to "Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)", I tried it in early hours, and it works for me.